# Add rows to datatable with a button asp.net VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I am wondering how to add rows to an already populated datatable with a button. the code I have so far is this...

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim dt As New DataTable("Dt")
        dt.Columns.Add("test1")
        dt.Columns.Add("test2")
        dt.Columns.Add("test3")

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click

        Dim dt As New DataTable

        dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works for me. Because am I storing the `DataTable` in `ViewState` so that I can reference the current data associated within the `DataTable` when it `postback`.
You are initializing `DataTable` in `Page_Load` method including header of `DataTable`. When you are clicking on btnadd button then you are not getting existing `DataSource`. If you assign `dt` in `ViewState("DataSource ")` in `Page_Load` method and declare again `DataTable` in `btnAdd_Click` method like `Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("DataSource "), DataTable)` then it will work because previous `DataSource` you are getting now. Finally I want to say that `DataSource`  doesn't remember the `DataSource` you set in a previous rendering of the page.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            Dim dt As New DataTable("Dt")
            dt.Columns.Add("test1")
            dt.Columns.Add("test2")
            dt.Columns.Add("test3")
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
            ViewState("DataSource ") = dt

        End Sub

        Protected Sub btnadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click

            Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("DataSource "), DataTable)
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
            dt.Rows.Add("Hi1", "Hi2", "Hi2")
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Sub
```

Comment: I will upvote this as a good answer if you add an explanation of how and why this works. Simply saying `it works for me.` doesn't give the OP any information as to why it works, what they missed out and what they should do. And, also fixup your formatting

Comment: This works, but I am only able to add one row at a time. Is there a way to continually add more rows?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work, just had to change a few things in the page loadout. thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @JayV Thanks for your suggestion. I have added little description. Hope that would be helpful.

Comment: @bman I am pleased that you were able to solve your all problems.